# Generating particular bit pattern using bitwise operators

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation

Here I want to generate a bit pattern to set `n` digits equal to `1` starting from position `p`.
Digits are numbered from `0 to 31`.
Following is what I did.

```
int bitPattern(int n, int p) {
    int hex, num1, num2;
    hex = 0x80000000;
    num1 = (hex >> (31 - p));
    num2 = (hex >> (31 - (n+p)));
    return num1 ^ num2;
}
```

*Example:*

```
bitPattern(6, 2) should return 
..000011111100
```

Any alternate solutions with less operators ?

Comment: You're invoking undefined behaviour when `n+p > 31`. If that's guaranteed to never be the case, you still have implementation-defined behaviour right-shifting a negative number. But if you're not afraid of UB, what about `((1 << n) - 1) << p`?

Comment: @DanielFischer in my problem `(n+p)` won't go beyond 31. and it is easy to identify too...

Comment: Anyway, if you only care about the bits, I'd recommend using an unsigned type, and then `((1 << n) - 1) << p` is safe unless `n` or `p` are negative or greater than or equal to the width of the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
return ((1<<n)-1)<<p;
```

To make `n` ones at position zero, compute `(2^n)-1`; recall that `2^n` is `1<<n`, so the expression becomes `((1<<n)-1)`. Now you need to add `p` zeros at the back, so shift the result left by `p`.